# useNavigate not working qwick-city even the Link is also not working when i try to navigate from a Component

Tags: typescript, qwik

Why `useNavigate` not working in the `header` component, even if i try to use the `Link` it's not working:

```
import { component$, useStylesScoped$ } from "@builder.io/qwik";
import styles from "./Header.css?inline";
import { useNavigate } from "@builder.io/qwik-city";
export default component$(() => {
  useStylesScoped$(styles);
  const nav = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div class="header">
      <img alt="logo" src="/icon.png" />
      <button
        onClick$={() => {
          alert();
          nav("/auth/logout");
        }}
      >
        LOGOUT
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});
```

I want to navigate to the `/auth/logout` but seems not working in this component. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely fine, restart your dev server again . If `/auth/logout` routes will exists then you will get page data otherwise you will get 404 page

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that when i was redirecting to the homepage when successifull authentication i was using `PERMANENT_REDIRECT` status code `301` so that's why it wasn't working:

```
export const onGet: RequestHandler = async (response) => {
  const token = response.cookie.get(TOKEN_KEY);
  const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3001/auth/me", {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token?.value ? token.value : ""}`,
    },
    credentials: "include",
  });

  const { me }: { me: MeType | null } = await res.json();

  if (me) {
    response.redirect(REDIRECT_CODES.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT, "/");
  }
};

export const useLogin = routeAction$(async (data, response) => {
  const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:3001/auth/login", {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    method: "POST",
  });
  const _data: {
    user: MeType | null;
    error: ErrorType | null;
    jwt: string | null;
  } = await res.json();
  if (_data.user && _data.jwt) {
    response.cookie.set(TOKEN_KEY, _data.jwt, cookiesOptions);
    response.redirect(REDIRECT_CODES.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT, "/");
  }
  return {
    success: true,
    error: _data.error,
  };
});
```

Changing my redirect status code to `307` solved the problem for me.

```
export enum REDIRECT_CODES {
  TEMPORARY_REDIRECT = 307,
  PERMANENT_REDIRECT = 308,
  MOVED_PERMANENTLY = 301,
}
```